# Tagging character matrices in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to come up with a way of encoding strings with character-level tags in NumPy. For example, given the following accepted characters:

```
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

The string:

```
s = ['1','b','a','c','3','4','1','1']
```

gets encoded as like so:

```
char_mat = np.array([[c]*len(chars) for c in chars])

s_mat = 1*(char_mat==s)
```

and the resulting `s_mat` looks like this:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Where each row corresponds to a character in `chars`, and each column corresponds to the position in the string. So the `a` in `s` is in the third column, the `b` is in the second, and so on.

Let's say I also have a class tag for each character in the string, and these are, for instance:

```
'1' 'b' 'a' 'c' '3' '4' '1' '1'
 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
 v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v
 1   2   2   0   0   3   3   1
```

I'd like to come up with a way of outputting a `tag_matrix` that has the same shape as `s_mat` but contains the tag for each element, like this:

```
array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]])
```

But I really can't figure out how to do this. Many thanks in advance for any help or suggestions. Note also that this is a small version of the actual problem I'm working on, in which strings are much longer, and the accepted characters include ascii lowercase, digits, and punctuation.

Comment: How do you define the class tags? using a list? Can you update your question? Seems like a simple multiplication would work no?

Comment: Shouldn't `char_mat` be defined as `np.array([[c]*len(s) for c in chars])`?

Comment: Thank you mozway, turns out I missed the obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as multiplying the class tags array with `s_mat`:

```py
class_tags = np.array([1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1])
tag_matrix = s_mat * class_tags
```